# Google Slides: Manipulate Guides via script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides

I'd like to add a custom set of predefined guides to my presentation, and thought I could do it via scripting. Looking at the [Developer's Reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/presentation#getSlides()) for the presentation, I don't see anything obvious (no getGuides()/setGuides() or anything). Does such a thing exist, or are guides non-accessible from script?

It's very difficult to search for because "google slides apps script guide" pulls up how-to pages about learning slides itself, not about the guides feature.

Comment: Currently there are no implemented properties for presentation guides and rulers in SlideApp or even the Slides API.

Comment: You probably mean something more robust by guide but you could load a grid image or ruler image as background with a master / theme which would be visible and help with positioning things added to the slide later.

Comment: @aNewb it's true, but for these purposes it needed to be the actual guide. Thanks